# CCS Flexbox Challenge - Content not lining up in box as required

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox, responsive

I have a requirement where four elements inside an outer flexbox need to line-up as below:

[image]

When the screen size reduces to 400px,

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {}
```

it needs to change and the brand name needs to go on top with the other elements aligning below to look like this:

[image]

However this is not currently how the code is working. In case of the desktop, the brand name is aligning to the top of the flexbox and the Select Box labels are not vertically left-aligning with their respective select boxes, as I need.

In the mobile view, the content is pouring out of the outer flexbox (Image2 Below):

[image]

[image]

Find below the complete code for the same:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery('#SortBy').select2({
    width: 'auto'
  });
  jQuery('#columnCheckboxes').select2({
    width: 'auto'
  });
  jQuery('#rowCheckboxes').select2({
    width: 'auto'
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: montserratbold, montserratregular, sans-serif;
}

.HeadingBar {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  background: #2a8aeb;
}

.Brand {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 30%;
  width: 30%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: center;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  margin: auto;
}

.Selectors {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  width: 70%;
}

.SelectorsSort {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 15%;
  padding: 1%
}

.SelectorsFilter {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 80%;
  padding: 1%
}

.SelectorFilterPhone {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  padding: 1%
}

.SelectorFilterParameter {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  padding: 1%
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  body {
    font-size: 80%;
  }
  .Brand {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    align-self: left;
    height: 40%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding-right: 2%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .Selectors {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .SelectorsSort {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 15%;
    padding: 1%
  }
  .SelectorsFilter {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 80%;
    padding: 1%
  }
  .SelectorFilterPhone {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 50%;
    padding: 1%
  }
  .SelectorFilterParameter {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 50%;
    padding: 1%
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div class="HeadingBar">
  <div class="Brand">
    Brand
  </div>
  <div class="Selectors">
    <div class="SelectorsSort">
      <div style="color:white; font-size: 120%">Sort:</div>
      <select id="SortBy">
        <option>--Sort By--</option>
        <option>Parameter1</option>
        <option>Parameter2</option>
        <option>Parameter3</option>
        <option>Parameter4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="SelectorsFilter">
      <div class="SelectorFilterPhone">
        <div style="color:white; font-size: 120%">Filter Phone:</div>
        <select id="columnCheckboxes">
          <option>--Filter Phone--</option>
          <option>Samsung</option>
          <option>Apple</option>
          <option>Xiomi</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="SelectorFilterParameter">
        <div style="color:white; font-size: 120%">Filter Parameters:</div>
        <select id="rowCheckboxes">
          <option>--Filter Parameter--</option>
          <option>Parameter1</option>
          <option>Parameter2</option>
          <option>Parameter3</option>
          <option>Parameter4</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help me with where I'm going wrong with the CCS for Flexbox, as I'm new to it and have been struggling with the it. :(

Comment: _“In case of the desktop, the brand name is aligning to the top of the flexbox”_ - your items are wrapping into two rows here, because their combined width is more than 100%.

Comment: If you change `padding-left` and `padding-right` for `.Brand` to 0 then it stays in one line.

Comment: Hi @cloned, I actually need 'Filter Phone' and 'Filter Parameter' to sit on top of their respective Select Boxes, like the first image I posted. This is not happening. :/

Comment: if you want to have them in a column layout you can set `flex-flow: column;` to these elements (for example for `.SelectorFilterPhone` )

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Hope this piece of code helps.

I would suggest you change the media query `max-width` to be `450px` instead of 400. Also, you might want to wrap the dropdown menus to be displayed in a column below 450px.

Do let me know if you need any clarification.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: montserratbold, montserratregular, sans-serif;
}

.HeadingBar {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  background: #2a8aeb;
}

.Brand {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 30%;
  width: 30%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: center;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  margin: auto;
}

.Selectors {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  width: 70%;
}

.SelectorsSort {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 1%
}

.SelectorsFilter {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 80%;
  padding: 1%;
  justify-content: space-evenly
}

.SelectorFilterPhone {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 1%
}

.SelectorFilterParameter {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 1%
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  body {
    font-size: 80%;
  }
  .Brand {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    align-self: left;
    height: 40%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding-right: 2%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .Selectors {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .SelectorsSort {
    flex: 1 1 15%;
    padding: 1%
  }
  
  .SelectorFilterPhone {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 1%
  }
  .SelectorFilterParameter {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 1%
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div class="HeadingBar">
  <div class="Brand">
    Brand
  </div>
  <div class="Selectors">
    <div class="SelectorsSort">
      <div style="color:white; font-size: 120%">Sort:</div>
      <select id="SortBy">
        <option>--Sort By--</option>
        <option>Parameter1</option>
        <option>Parameter2</option>
        <option>Parameter3</option>
        <option>Parameter4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="SelectorFilterPhone">
      <div style="color:white; font-size: 120%">Filter Phone:</div>
      <select id="columnCheckboxes">
        <option>--Filter Phone--</option>
        <option>Samsung</option>
        <option>Apple</option>
        <option>Xiomi</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="SelectorFilterParameter">
      <div style="color:white; font-size: 120%">Filter Parameters:</div>
      <select id="rowCheckboxes">
        <option>--Filter Parameter--</option>
        <option>Parameter1</option>
        <option>Parameter2</option>
        <option>Parameter3</option>
        <option>Parameter4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Ziyad! Thanks for the reply! But this still doesn't the get me the layout I'm looking for like the 1st and 2nd image I posted where  'Filter Phone' and 'Filter Parameter' to sit on top of their respective Select Boxes, like the first image I posted. This is still not happening. Thanks again!!